# Melt a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, melt

I have a `pandas DataFrame` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'custid':[1,2,3,4],
...: 'prod1':['jeans','tshirt','jacket','tshirt'],
...: 'prod1_hnode1':[1,2,3,2],
...: 'prod1_hnode2':[6,7,8,7],
...: 'prod2':['tshirt','jeans','jacket','shirt'],
...: 'prod2_hnode1':[2,1,3,4],
...: 'prod2_hnode2':[7,6,8,7]})

In [54]: df
Out[54]: 
    custid   prod1  prod1_hnode1  prod1_hnode2   prod2  prod2_hnode1  \
0       1   jeans             1             6  tshirt             2   
1       2  tshirt             2             7   jeans             1   
2       3  jacket             3             8  jacket             3   
3       4  tshirt             2             7   shirt             4   

   prod2_hnode2  
0             7  
1             6  
2             8  
3             7
```

How can I convert this to the following format:

```
dfnew = pd.DataFrame({'custid':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],
...: 'prod':['prod1','prod2','prod1','prod2','prod1','prod2','prod1','prod2'],
...: 'rec':['jeans','tshirt','tshirt','jeans','jacket','jacket','tshirt','shirt'],
...: 'hnode1':[1,2,2,1,3,3,2,4],
...: 'hnode2':[6,7,7,6,8,8,7,7]})


In [56]: dfnew
Out[56]: 
   custid  hnode1  hnode2   prod     rec
0       1       1       6  prod1   jeans
1       1       2       7  prod2  tshirt
2       2       2       7  prod1  tshirt
3       2       1       6  prod2   jeans
4       3       3       8  prod1  jacket
5       3       3       8  prod2  jacket
6       4       2       7  prod1  tshirt
7       4       4       7  prod2   shirt
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Have you tried [pivoting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) ?

Comment: @SouradeepNanda I think pivoting is the opposite of what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by column `custid`
- create `MultiIndex` in columns by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)
- replace `NaN`s in columns by `rec`
- [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) by first level
- [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex`
- rename column

---

```
df = df.set_index('custid')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.rename(columns={np.nan:'rec'})
cols = ['custid','hnode1','hnode2','prod','rec']
df = df.stack(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'prod'}).reindex(columns=cols)
print (df)
   custid  hnode1  hnode2   prod     rec
0       1       1       6  prod1   jeans
1       1       2       7  prod2  tshirt
2       2       2       7  prod1  tshirt
3       2       1       6  prod2   jeans
4       3       3       8  prod1  jacket
5       3       3       8  prod2  jacket
6       4       2       7  prod1  tshirt
7       4       4       7  prod2   shirt
```

Comment: Very nice solution !

Comment: @MaxU - Thanks, the hardest was replace NaNs in columns.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks a lot. I was not able to solve this even in `R` in which I majorly code. Long way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that should work, but uses repeated `melt`s.

```
coln = df.dtypes.index  # save some typing
df_long = pd.melt(
    df, id_vars = "custid", value_vars = ["prod1", "prod2"],
    var_name = "prod", value_name = "rec").assign(
    hnode1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars = "custid", 
                     value_vars = filter(lambda x: "hnode1" in x, coln))["value"],
    hnode2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars = "custid", 
                     value_vars = filter(lambda x: "hnode2" in x, coln))["value"])
print(df_long)
   custid   prod     rec  hnode1  hnode2
0       1  prod1   jeans       1       6
1       2  prod1  tshirt       2       7
2       3  prod1  jacket       3       8
3       4  prod1  tshirt       2       7
4       1  prod2  tshirt       2       7
5       2  prod2   jeans       1       6
6       3  prod2  jacket       3       8
7       4  prod2   shirt       4       7
```

---

You mention R in your comments. `melt` from "data.table" should be able to handle this much more easily since you can melt multiple sets of columns at once, similar to how you might approach the problem with base R's `reshape` function.

The base R approach might be something along the lines of:

```
reshape(df, direction = "long", idvar = "custid", 
        varying = list(c(2, 5), c(3, 6), c(4, 7)), 
        sep = "", times = c("prod1", "prod2"))
```